# How do I get the ScreenSize programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-screen

Android defines screen sizes as Normal Large XLarge etc.

It automatically picks between static resources in appropriate folders. I need this data about the current device in my java code. The DisplayMetrics only gives information about the current device density. Nothing is available regarding screen size.

I did find the ScreenSize enum in grep code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.android/common/r16/com/android/resources/ScreenSize.java?av=h#ScreenSize)
However this does not seem available to me for 4.0 SDK. Is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Copy and paste this code into your `Activity` and when it is executed it will `Toast` the device's screen size category.

```
int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

String toastMsg;
switch(screenSize) {
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
        toastMsg = "Large screen";
        break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
        toastMsg = "Normal screen";
        break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
        toastMsg = "Small screen";
        break;
    default:
        toastMsg = "Screen size is neither large, normal or small";
}
Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: i used this above and run it different emulator like large,medium,small. but i get toast normal screen..how to solve it

Answer (score 72):

```
private static String getScreenResolution(Context context)
{
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    return "{" + width + "," + height + "}";
}
```

Comment: your code is giving result excluding soft touch buttons in bottom and status bar and toolbar in top @David

Comment: Exactly what I wanted ! Works like a charm

Comment: Thanks. This code works fine for me on android emulator phones and tablets. But when I rotate the tablet, the resolution numbers are not inverted instead the actual value is changes. But for phone it works fine. How can I solve this?

Comment: It's help me a lot. It's really helpful when you use animations in Android , and theLayout weight and Layout percentage are not use.

Answer (score 5):

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: Thanks. This code works fine for me on android emulator phones and tablets. But when I rotate the tablet, the resolution numbers are not inverted instead the actual value is changes. But for phone it works fine. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a pretty straight forward simple piece of code!

```
public Map<String, Integer> deriveMetrics(Activity activity) {
    try {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        if (activity != null) {
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        }

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("screenWidth", Integer.valueOf(metrics.widthPixels));
        map.put("screenHeight", Integer.valueOf(metrics.heightPixels));
        map.put("screenDensity", Integer.valueOf(metrics.densityDpi));

        return map;
    } catch (Exception err) {
        ; // just use zero values
        return null;
    }
}
```

This method now can be used anywhere independently. Wherever you want to get information about device screen do it as follows:

```
        Map<String, Integer> map = deriveMetrics2(this);
        map.get("screenWidth");
        map.get("screenHeight");
        map.get("screenDensity");
```

Hope this might be helpful to someone out there and may find it easier to use.
If I need to re-correct or improve please don't hesitate to let me know! :-)

Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks. This code works fine for me on android emulator phones and tablets. But when I rotate the tablet, the resolution numbers are not inverted instead the actual value is changes. But for phone it works fine. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Ways to get DisplayMetrics:

1.

```
val dm = activity.resources.displayMetrics
```

2. 

```
val dm = DisplayMetrics() 
activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(dm)
```

3. val dm = DisplayMetrics()
   val wm = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
   wm..defaultDisplay.getMetrics(dm)

then get

The screen density expressed as dots-per-inch. May be either DENSITY_LOW, DENSITY_MEDIUM, or DENSITY_HIGH

```
dm.densityDpi
```

The absolute height of the available display size in pixels.

```
dm.heightPixels
```

The absolute width of the available display size in pixels.

```
dm.widthPixels
```

The exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the X dimension.

```
dm.xdpi
```

The exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the Y dimension.

```
dm.ydpi
```

[DisplayMetrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics)

Answer (score 3):

You can get display size in pixels using this code.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
SizeUtils.SCREEN_WIDTH = display.getWidth();
SizeUtils.SCREEN_HEIGHT = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: `getHeight` and `getWidth` are deprecated as of API 16: Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean)

Answer (score 3):

The code will give you the result in the following format: width x height

```
String displayResolution = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels + "x" + getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Comment: What if device that OP is using it not 1440x2560? Your answer should be more specific. Code may be good, but description will not be always valid.

Answer (score 2):

With decorations (including button bar):

```
private static String getScreenResolution(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
    return "{" + metrics.widthPixels + "," + metrics.heightPixels + "}";
}
```

Without decorations:

```
private static String getScreenResolution(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    return "{" + metrics.widthPixels + "," + metrics.heightPixels + "}";
}
```

The difference is the method **getMetrics()** vs **getRealMetrics()** of the Display class.

Answer (score 1):

simon-

Different screen sizes have different pixel densities. A 4 inch display on your phone could have more or less pixels then say a 26 inch TV. If Im understanding correctly he wants to detect which of the size groups the current screen is, small, normal, large, and extra large. The only thing I can think of is to detect the pixel density and use that to determine the actual size of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I need this for a couple of my apps and the following code was my solution to the problem. Just showing the code inside onCreate. This is a stand alone app to run on any device to return the screen info.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSize);

    density = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.density);
    densityDpi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.densityDpi);
    widthPixels = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.widthPixels);
    xdpi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xdpi);
    ydpi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ydpi);

    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Large screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        txSize.setText("Large screen");
    } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Normal sized screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        txSize.setText("Normal sized screen");
    } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Small sized screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        txSize.setText("Small sized screen");
    } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "xLarge sized screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        txSize.setText("Small sized screen");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Screen size is neither large, normal or small",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        txSize.setText("Screen size is neither large, normal or small");
    }

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);

    Log.i(TAG, "density :" + metrics.density);
    density.setText("density :" + metrics.density);

    Log.i(TAG, "D density :" + metrics.densityDpi);
    densityDpi.setText("densityDpi :" + metrics.densityDpi);

    Log.i(TAG, "width pix :" + metrics.widthPixels);
    widthPixels.setText("widthPixels :" + metrics.widthPixels);

    Log.i(TAG, "xdpi :" + metrics.xdpi);
    xdpi.setText("xdpi :" + metrics.xdpi);

    Log.i(TAG, "ydpi :" + metrics.ydpi);
    ydpi.setText("ydpi :" + metrics.ydpi);
```

And a simple XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSize"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/density"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/densityDpi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widthPixels"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/xdpi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ydpi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a non-activity i.e. Fragment, Adapter, Model class or any other java class that do not extends `Activity` simply `getResources()` will not work. You can use `getActivity()` in fragment or use `context` that you pass to the corresponding class.

```
mContext.getResources()
```

I would recommend making a class say Utils that will have method/Methods for the common work. The benefit for this is you can get desired result with single line of code anywhere in the app calling this method.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm below can be used to identify which category will be used for picking between the static resources and also caters for the newer XX and XXX high densities

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    mDensityDpi = displayMetrics.densityDpi;
    mDensity = displayMetrics.density;
    mDisplayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    mDisplayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    String densityStr = "Unknown";
    int difference, leastDifference = 9999;

    difference = Math.abs(mDensityDpi - DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW);
    if (difference < leastDifference) {
        leastDifference = difference;
        densityStr = "LOW";
    }

    difference = Math.abs(mDensityDpi - DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM);
    if (difference < leastDifference) {
        leastDifference = difference;
        densityStr = "MEDIUM";
    }

    difference = Math.abs(mDensityDpi - DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH);
    if (difference < leastDifference) {
        leastDifference = difference;
        densityStr = "HIGH";
    }

    difference = Math.abs(mDensityDpi - DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH);
    if (difference < leastDifference) {
        leastDifference = difference;
        densityStr = "XHIGH";
    }

    difference = Math.abs(mDensityDpi - DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH);
    if (difference < leastDifference) {
        leastDifference = difference;
        densityStr = "XXHIGH";
    }

    difference = Math.abs(mDensityDpi - DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH);
    if (difference < leastDifference) {
        densityStr = "XXXHIGH";
    }

    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Display [h,w]: [%s,%s] Density: %s Density DPI: %s [%s]", mDisplayHeight, mDisplayWidth, mDensity, mDensityDpi, densityStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get screen resolution or screen size in Kotlin

```
fun getScreenResolution(context: Context): Pair<Int, Int> {
    try {
        val wm = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        val display = wm.defaultDisplay
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
        display.getMetrics(metrics)
        val width = metrics.widthPixels
        val height = metrics.heightPixels
        //Log.d(AppData.TAG, "screenSize: $width, $height")
        return Pair(width, height)

    } catch (error: Exception) {
        Log.d(AppData.TAG, "Error : autoCreateTable()", error)
    }

    return Pair(0, 0)
}
```