# How to find the device as LDPI MDPI HDPI or XHDPI

Tags: android, android-screen

Without any code snippet for the application, how to get screen resolution and length of the screen. How could I find whether the device is ldpi, mdpi , hdpi or xhdpi ?

Comment: No, I don't want to code and find the device type ?

Comment: its kind of late but There was this app on the playstore which will get you what you are looking for without writing a code snippet but unfortunately the app is removed from google play store but i was able to extract the apk from my installed device and have uploaded it to following link:

https://www.mediafire.com/?2jccjo17mvxgljt

Hope this helps you in getting what are you looking for.
Do let me know if that helped you or not

Comment: If you want a quick reference, Google provides screen details of a few popular devices: https://design.google.com/devices/

Answer (score 72):

**Edit:**
use `DisplayMetrics` to get the density of the screen

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
```

this will return the int value that represents the following constants.
`DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW ,DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH`

```
  int density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

switch(density)
{
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
   Toast.makeText(context, "LDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
     Toast.makeText(context, "MDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    Toast.makeText(context, "HDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
     Toast.makeText(context, "XHDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
}
```

This will return 
 following constants based on thsi you can identify the device

---

Try this

```
int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

switch(screenSize) {
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Large screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Normal screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Small screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    default:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Screen size is neither large, normal or small" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Source [Identifying screen resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11252278/450534)

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question. It's asking about density, not size.

Comment: @SiddharthLele I have found it because of you....thanks

Comment: I dont want to code - seeing the mobile could I? Purpose : Samsung S4 is coming to market in march - I want to know the density ,

Comment: @Sreeram "seeing the mobile" in the sense...you can find the phone spefications in http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s_iv-5125.php

Comment: @Pragnani - Might be fundamental but please ignore - Using GSM arena, how could I find the device device - Now my objective is to find S4 belongs to HDPI/XHDPI.

Comment: @Sreeram That is what we(me and Gabe Sechan) have posted. I'll update it for you make you clear

Comment: As per what Gabe and you posted, I need to code the snippet - run it on the device and find the device type. But the requirement is looking at the device , knowing the screen spec's - could I find the device type - I remember a formula not clear   [square root of width* height]/length .. blah blah .. if the value is <1 >1 >1.25 >1.50 I could find the device type. Could you explain it  for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int density = dm.densityDpi;
```

The density variable is a constant defined in DisplayMetrics corresponding to the different dpis.

Comment: I dont want to code - seeing the mobile could I? Purpose : Samsung S4 is coming to market in march - I want to know the density ,

Comment: Use google and search then.  And then you're asking on the wrong site-  this is a site for asking programming questions, not about device specs.