# How to set Different Orientation for tablet and mobile in android

Tags: android, screen, orientation

I want to set `Portrait Orientation` and lock for `ldpi and mdpi screens`. and want to set Landscape orientation and lock for `hdpi and xhdpi`.

When app opened in `10 inch tablets` it should be `landscape` it cant be `portrait`. like that when the app opened in `android mobile` it should be in `portrait` `not landscape`.

So please help me to fix this issue.

Please Refer this Question, its works for me :)

[How to check an Android device is HDPI screen or MDPI screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099550/how-to-check-an-android-device-is-hdpi-screen-or-mdpi-screen)

```
        switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Here What is your issue??

Comment: @Homosapiens he stated his issue clearly

Comment: @GopalRao he just want to do that but it seems no research/effort.

Comment: @Homosapiens what kind of research i have to do? many documents and blogs are telling we can lock orientation for a app, Example if we set orientation in android manifest file it would applicable for all devices, if i set Portrait orientation for all devices its portrait. but i want in low size screens it should be portrait and high size screens it should be landscape. how i have to research for this? if you tell i will do for sure.

Comment: @Homosapiens also there are millions of question already raised in stack-overflow and almost most of them are answered well. if there is no question similar to what i want then only we are asking by raise new Question. We are not blindly come and post questions. please try to understood bro.

Comment: @rkaartikeyan cool bro. Really i did not mean that. Any how you can do this by write a code in your Activity. Do it in run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061238/how-to-find-the-device-as-ldpi-mdpi-hdpi-or-xhdpi) to find whether device is hdpi or mdpi or xhdpi etc etc.

based on that lock your screen orientation.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (ldpi || mdpi) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    } else if(hdpi || xhdpi) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks This works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099550/how-to-check-an-android-device-is-hdpi-screen-or-mdpi-screen