# What are standard 4 android screen sizes?

Tags: android, screen-size

What are standard 4 android screen sizes ?
are they ?

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

how can I get the these widths using the code ?

Comment: Do you want to get all four, or do you want the know the screen size of the device the app is running on?

Comment: You should take a link at this
[Android designing for multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

Very usefull link: [ScreenSize Overview](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

The definitions are:

- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp.
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp.
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp. (Android does not currently support screens smaller than this.)

Here are some more examples of how this works with real screens:

- A QVGA screen is 320x240 ldpi. Converting to mdpi (a 4/3 scaling factor) gives us 426dp x 320dp; this matches the minimum size above for the small screen bucket.
- The Xoom is a typical 10” tablet with a 1280x800 mdpi screen. This places it into the xlarge screen bucket.
- The Dell Streak is a 800x480 mdpi screen. This places it into the bottom of the large size bucket.
- A typical 7” tablet has a 1024x600 mdpi screen. This also counts as a large screen.
- The original Samsung Galaxy Tab is an interesting case. Physically it is a 1024x600 7” screen and thus classified as “large”. However the device configures its screen as hdpi, which means after applying the appropriate ⅔ scaling factor the actual space on the screen is 682dp x 400dp. This actually moves it out of the “large” bucket and into a “normal” screen size. The Tab actually reports that it is “large”; this was a mistake in the framework’s computation of the size for that device that we made. Today no devices should ship like this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of what you are trying to achieve... If you want to have a **specific layout** for a **specific screen size**, you can create a new folder called `layout-large`, for example.
See the [android developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support).

If you want to get the **actual screen size** programmatically, then you can use this :

```
int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11252278/1424030).