# Android get wrong screen size

Tags: android

I create android emulator with screen:
screen size: 7.5 inches
Resolution(width x height): 720x960
density: mdpi
And in Android virtual device manager it is shown xlarge screen size but in following code it returns Large screen size.

```
int screenLayout = context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
screenLayout &= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

switch (screenLayout) {
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
        return ScreenSize.SMALL;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
        return ScreenSize.MEDIUM;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
        return ScreenSize.LARGE;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
        return ScreenSize.XLARGE;
    default:
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the ScreenSize programmatically in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252067/how-do-i-get-the-screensize-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: following Google document https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp.

Comment: I don't want to get width or height I just want to determine screen size (Small, Normal, Large or xLarge) but I don't know why it return wrong screen size

Comment: try with density --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/19557542/5188159  second part

Comment: I already set mdpi density for android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to get screen Height and Width using:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: I don't wanna width or height I just wanna determine screen size but I don't know it return wrong screen size

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code to get Height and Width of Android Phone Screen .

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width= displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

getscreen Height and width use 
`int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();`
get layout Height use
`int layoutHeight = Layout.getMeasuredHeight();`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getScreenWidth() {
return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}

public static int getScreenHeight() {
return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
/**  
 * Get screen width  
 *  
 * @param context  
 * @return  screen width
 */  
public static int getScreenWidth(Context context)  
{  
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context  
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);  
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();  
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(outMetrics);  
    return outMetrics.widthPixels;  
}  

/**  
 * Get screen height  
 *  
 * @param context  
 * @return  screen height
 */  
public static int getScreenHeight(Context context)  
{  
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context  
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);  
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();  
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(outMetrics);  
    return outMetrics.heightPixels;  
}
```